# Apache <LocationMatch> using x-forwared-for

Tags: apache-virtualhost

Is is possible to 'LocationMatch' and have Apache 2.4 use the x-forwarded-for IP address? I'm unable to use 'mod_rpaf' or 'mod_remoteip for this.

I have configured the 'apache.conf' LogFormat to use the x-forwarded-for IP, which is working, but Apache 'LocationMatch' is still pulling the LoadBalancer IP.

```
<LocationMatch "(?i).*/CFIDE">
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 10.0.0.0/8 # I need this 'Allow' to use the x-forwared-for IP
</LocationMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own issue by using 'SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR'.

```
<LocationMatch "(?i).*/CFIDE">
SetEnvIF X-FORWARDED-FOR "123.456.654.321" AllowIP
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=AllowIP
</LocationMatch>
```